# Asus X509F BIOS Boot troubles

Tags: boot

I am trying to install Windows 10 on a new laptop Asus X509F (no previous OS). I have a problem with the BIOS. In the Aption Setup Utility, I do not see an option for USB. In fact, there are no other options except Fast Boot. I've disabled Fast Boot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGEAg.png)Also, I've disabled Secure Boot. Any idea?

Comment: At Save&Exit you should have a boot override option. And a one time boot menu which is independent from the main UEFI settings. Check your manual.